# foreach output a set number of arrays only

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, count, iteration

How would I output only a set of numbers in an array, say if theres 10 arrays, I would only like to output 8 of them?

```
foreach($arrays as $array){
 //do I use a for loop/
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` is only the natural approach if you actually want to iterate over **each** item (as the name implies).  However, you could do something like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($arrays as $array){
    ...
    $i++;
    if ($i == $limit) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
foreach($arrays as $array){
   if($i < 8){
        // do something
   }
   $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(array_slice($arrays, 0, 8) as $array){
 //do I use a for loop/
}
```

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: yep (see the fourth argument of `array_slice`). But as long as OP doesn't use key in his example - I omitted it

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `foreach` loop like this (already mentioned).

```
$i = 0;
foreach($arrays as $array){
 //do I use a for loop/

 if(++$i >= 8) break;
}
```

...or you can use a `for` loop, which is designed for doing actions a set number of times, e.g., 8 times.

```
for($i=0; $i < 8; $i++){
 $array = $arrays[$i];

 // body
}
```

Comment: ```$arrays``` can't be an associative array.  ```$array``` can be any type (associative array, array, string, integer, it doesn't matter).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: `$arrays can't be an associative array.` --- you're just wrong. And your second case will fail in case if non-natural order is used

Comment: "you're just wrong"  how so?  I was specifically talking about the ```for``` example.  If you have ```array('a'=>'b')``` you will be assigning ```NULL``` each iteration.

Comment: `you will be assigning NULL each iteration.` --- exactly. Instead of expected array you'll have `null` and notice. That is fail